# Error while checking if a string contains an element from a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, any

So I'm trying to use the any() function to search through a user inputted string and see if it contains any elements from a list:

```
# takes the user input
i = raw_input(">>> ")
e = i.lower()
af.inp.append(e)

# greeting section
if any(x in e for x in af.x):
    af.greeting()
```

List:

```
 x = ["hello", "hi", "hey"] # greetings
```

So basically I'm having a problem where if I input any string that contains any characters found in the list it will return the greeting function...

This is a problem seeing as if I input "Shit" rather than "Hi" it will run the greeting function. I think I may be using the wrong function to search for specific whole words or strings found in the user inputted text rather than parts of a word: ex. "S'hi't" rather than "Hi".

Anybody know a way around this or if there is a different way I can go about searching for whole words or strings?

p.s. Just to clarify I understand why this is happening using the any function I am just wondering If there is any way around this or a different method all together.

Comment: You're going to have to explain what `af`, `af.inp` and `af.x` are.

Comment: "af" is the module containing all of the lists I am running through... af.x is the list containing all the greeting words (I included this portion of the code in the initial comment) and af.inp is the list that I am pushing the user input into in order to save it

Comment: None of that is important to the question. Why include it?

Comment: I'd figure I would give 1 extra line of code just for context? There's literally 6 lines of code here if reading an extra one is too much of a problem for you how do you have the effort to reply with a complaint?

Comment: Try to [create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your example was none of these. It's not the effort of reading an extra line that I'm complaining about, it's the lack of effort on your part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wan to check for existence of your words in list `x` so you need to **split** your input then use `any` :

```
i = raw_input(">>> ")
e = i.lower().split()
af.inp.append(e)

# greeting section
if any(x in e for x in af.x):
    af.greeting()
```

Or you can simply put your words in a `set` object and use `set.intersection` method :

```
x = {"hello", "hi", "hey"}
if x.intersections(af.x):
    af.greeting()
```

Comment: Now when I try to input a word not containing characters from the greetings list I am getting this error:                                                     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 30, in <module>
    elif e in af.wu:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: @TreyTaylor How you did that? this error occurs when you use a list in `set` object

Comment: I would except the answer but I don't have 15 reputation yet :( Sorry.

Comment: @TreyTaylor Yep, its OK, you can do it when you reach to 15 ;)

Answer (score 1):

`str.split()` would work for most of your cases, but would fail if you input something like - `'hey! how are you?'` or so. I think you should use regex here. Example -

```
import re
if any(re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(x),e) for x in af.x):
    af.greeting()
```

Example/Demo -

```
>>> import re
>>> e = 'hey! how are you?'
>>> xx = ["hello", "hi", "hey"]
>>> if any(re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(x),e) for x in xx):
...     print('Hello to you too!')
...
Hello to you too!
>>> e = 'shit'
>>> if any(re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(x),e) for x in xx):
...     print('Hello to you too!')
...
>>>
>>> e = 'hi you'
>>> if any(re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(x),e) for x in xx):
...     print('Hello to you too!')
...
Hello to you too!
```

Comment: Thanks I think I'll try this out!